# QUERY_STRING и переменная

Tags: php

Есть ссылка `index.php?del=$ID`. `ID` может быть любой, например от 1 до 99999. Как ловить и обрабатывать этот ID с помощью `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`?

```
if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] == 'del=$ID') {echo "Гуд!";}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У этой функции есть один неприятный косяк. Она может проверять только те числа, которые не превышают максимальное значение числа в PHP.

```
if (isset($_GET['del']) AND preg_match('/^[\d]+$/', $_GET['del'])
{
/// что-нить делаем, т. к. данные безопасны
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Для безопасного получения значения из параметра (GET, POST, и т.д.) используйте [`filter_input`](https://php.net/manual/ru/function.filter-input.php)

```
<?php

$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'del', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

if (null === $id) {
    // del - отсуствует
}

if (false === $id) {
    // не прошел валидацию
}

var_dump($id); // $id - integer
```